# Integrating Google Drive with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-drive-api

I'm working on app in which I need to integrate with Google Drive for my iOS App.
So I started following [Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart). Every thing worked perfectly fine and successfully able to get list of my file with the use of query in `GTLQueryDrive` class. But problem is that I am getting every thing for using query so for this there is no User Interface for Google Drive (like they can show all files with logos and we can get those file and some delegate may trigger as I also noticed in android integrated project). So

- Is this possible that I Google drive give some default interface for listing files with actions available, instead of just using queries.
- If possible then how can Integrate or some helping tutorial link.

Looking for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Is this possible that I Google drive give some default interface for listing files with actions available, instead of just using queries?**

It seems what you're looking for is the *Google Picker*.

> It's is a "File Open" dialog for the information stored in Google
>   servers. With Google Picker, your users can access and upload photos,
>   videos, maps, and documents stored in Google servers. The selection is
>   passed back to your web page or web application for further use. You
>   can read more of that [in the
>   docs](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/).

I have to mention though that the example used is written in Javascript.

**If possible then how can Integrate or some helping tutorial link.**

Try this [iOS Picker demo app](https://github.com/aytek/iOS-Swift-Google-Drive-Document-Picker) from Github.

For additional info about implementing Picker, watch this [video from Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjnXelh_cE8).